# Using ports instead of HTTP request to tell server which site to serve

Tags: http, https, port

Are there any drawbacks to using ports to tell my server which website to return instead of getting that info from the HTTP request? Is there a best practice to decide which port range to use?

As I understand, it may be difficult to use HTTPS if I rely on the HTTP request, although I don't intend to use HTTPS at the moment.

I believe I can set a DNS record in each website domain telling it which port to map to on my server via a SRV record.

The server is a simple golang program using the HTTP library. The machine is a Debian VM hosted through Google Compute Engine with a static IP address. Either option depends on the golang library allowing me to specify a port or allowing me to parse the http request, both which I believe I can do. I believe the port option will result in running multiple server "processes" which will be separate golang programs which may be complex to manage (keeping track of which sites are on which ports) while the HTTP request option will result in running a single server process that can serve all of the websites, which may be a little more complex to set up but easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick with using vhosts and let apache determine which site to serve via the headers. Using a port other than 80 and assuming the client will figure it out from the SRV records will not work.

All modern browsers support this approach, and newer versions of apache and web browsers even support this using TLS, in case you do eventually decide to switch to HTTPS.

Comment: Sorry, should have made it more clear. This server is not running Apache. It is a small server written in golang (example of a simple golang http server: http://thenewstack.io/building-a-web-server-in-go/). The SRV record settings are transparent to users.

Comment: Some users behind enterprise firewalls will just be unable to reach your sites running on non-WKS ports. And after all, this approach is just weird. It's like reinventing the internet of some worse kind. In a modern reality running a public web-server on a port other than 80 or 443  is considered weird and bad-styled.

Comment: My only hangup for using the HTTP request header is that I have to lump all these separate web apps in one executable, which doesn't feel like a good approach.

Comment: While SRV records are there to be consumed by a client to find a particular service, http port 80 is well-known and clients aren't going to go looking at your SRV records to determine what port to use since the full URL http://host:80 always assumes port 80 if not given.

Comment: Clients don't determine whether the port requested on is 80 or otherwise, it's handled by the DNS settings of the domain.

Comment: @sup3rs3nior that would be an incorrect statement. The DNS lookup will return an IP address when queried for the A (or AAAA) record. There is not a "connect on this port" in the answer from DNS. The client makes a defacto request on port 80 unless the requested resource contains a specified port. When left unspecified, it is defined as port 80. See section 3.3 in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738

Comment: @sup3rs3nior Putting them in one executable is not a very good approach, no. Most business environments put a proxying application, load balancer, or webserver in front of the application servers in order to minimize the role they have in request routing.

Comment: Ah, thank you  @LinuxNinja, I did not correctly understand what a SRV record would do.

Comment: @AndrewB the load balancing happens at the VM level.

Comment: @LinuxNinja thank you very much for your help. Your feedback about sticking with HTTP parsing and the option to use TLS has led me to this server written in golang that correctly implements what you are talking about: I believe I have arrived at the correct answer. I found this golang server that correctly implements both HTTP parsing and TSL https://caddyserver.com/docs/tls

Comment: @LinuxNinja I've marked your answer as accepted. Although I tried to upvote this answer, I don't yet have the reputation for it to register. None the less thank you very much.

Comment: I think I found a simpler solution than caddyserver. I found this guide which explains how to let each app run on its own port and let nginx (or apache) route incoming requests from port 80 to each app (80 > 8001, 8002, 8003...) based on the url requested. http://evanbyrne.com/blog/go-production-server-ubuntu-nginx